# BizTalk 2009 to 2010 upgrade path

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009

We are moving to BTS 2010 and I would like to know if I can simply redeploy our 2009 apps onto 2010?

I have tried finding this information out on the web and I have found anecdotal evidence of people saying the 2009 apps run on 2010 but nothing from Microsoft on the issue.

Microsoft released this document [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/F/0FFEF5D0-BE04-4D03-9125-75B8AD243E57/Upgrading%2520to%2520BizTalk%2520Server%25202010%2520from%2520BizTalk%2520Server%25202009%2520or%25202006%2520R2.docx&ei=3R3PUNnzBYqH0AXP9YHwDA&usg=AFQjCNHoWG5Xp4NfkbudqvenuZVVzOSaLA&sig2=-OOqchko_mchgfJVEDswJA) about the *in-place* upgrade path, but this does not mention apps at all. Additionally we are not looking to do an in-place upgrade but to build a completely new environment for 2010 and then switch it over.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certainly it works - we've installed MSI's generated off our BizTalk 2009 / VS 2008 environments directly onto BTS 2010, including retention of the 2009 binding files. The BTS 2010 environment was a multi-server clean install.

In fact, many of our incumbent, stable BTS 2009 apps are still running on our BTS 2010 prod servers - we haven't bothered to rebuild them.

Comment: Thanks for this definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

According to [Jeremie Devillard](http://jeremiedevillard.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/upgrade-biztalk-server-2009-to-biztalk-server-2010) it is possible to deploy 2009 apps on a new 2010 environment (see comments section).

Many thanks Jeremie.